# MVC3 - an entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of ientitychangetracker

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I went through similar questions but it dint solve my purpose. 
Im using the same code in 2 ways : 1. directly through button press 2. Through scheduled tasks.

By method 1 it works fine but method 2 gives that error.
My code :

Service -

```
public virtual int SendCampaign(Campaign campaign, EmailAccount emailAccount,
        IEnumerable<NewsLetterSubscription> subscriptions)
    {
        var campaignSubscriberTrack = new CampaignNewsletterSubscriberTrack();  

        if (campaign == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("campaign");

        if (emailAccount == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("emailAccount");

        int totalEmailsSent = 0;

        foreach (var subscription in subscriptions)
        {
            var tokens = new List<Token>();
            _messageTokenProvider.AddStoreTokens(tokens);
            _messageTokenProvider.AddNewsLetterSubscriptionTokens(tokens, subscription);

            string subject = _tokenizer.Replace(campaign.Subject, tokens, false);
            string body = _tokenizer.Replace(campaign.Body, tokens, true);

            var email = new QueuedEmail()
            {
                Priority = 3,
                From = emailAccount.Email,
                FromName = emailAccount.DisplayName,
                To = subscription.Email,
                Subject = subject,
                Body = body,
                CreatedOnUtc = DateTime.UtcNow,
                EmailAccountId = emailAccount.Id
            };
            _queuedEmailService.InsertQueuedEmail(email);
            totalEmailsSent++;

            campaignSubscriberTrack.CampaignId = campaign.Id;
            campaignSubscriberTrack.NewsletterSubscriberId = subscription.Id;
            campaignSubscriberTrack.Campaign = campaign;
            campaignSubscriberTrack.NewsletterSubscription = subscription;
            campaignSubscriberTrack.IsEmailOpened = 0;
            campaignSubscriberTrack.OpenedOnUtc = null;
            Guid guid;
            string id = tokens.Where(t => t.Key.Equals("TrackImage")).Select(t => t.Value).FirstOrDefault();
            var lastPart = (id.Split('/').Last()).Split('=').Last();
            if (lastPart != null)
            {
                guid = new Guid(lastPart);
                campaignSubscriberTrack.ImageGUID = guid;
            }

            ***InsertCampaignNewsletterSubscriberTrack(campaignSubscriberTrack);***

        }
        campaign.CampaignSchedulingTime = 0;
        UpdateCampaign(campaign); 

        return totalEmailsSent;
    }
```

Class -

```
public partial class CampaignNewsletterSubscriberTrack 
    {
        public virtual Campaign Campaign { get; set; }
        public virtual int CampaignId { get; set; }
        public virtual NewsLetterSubscription NewsletterSubscription { get; set; }
        public virtual int NewsletterSubscriberId { get; set; }
        public virtual int IsEmailOpened { get; set; }
        public virtual DateTime? OpenedOnUtc { get; set; }
        public virtual Guid ImageGUID { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Model -

```
public class CampaignNewsletterSubscriberTrackModel
{
    public int CampaignId { get; set; }

    public int NewsletterSubscriberId { get; set; }

    public int IsEmailOpened { get; set; }

    public DateTime? OpenedOnUtc { get; set; }

    public Guid ImageGUID { get; set; }
}
```

And in this function the record gets inserted -

```
public virtual void InsertCampaignNewsletterSubscriberTrack(CampaignNewsletterSubscriberTrack track)
        {
            if (track == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("track");

            _campaignNewsletterSubscriberTrackRepository.Insert(track);
        }
```

Error occurs at --> InsertCampaignNewsletterSubscriberTrack(campaignSubscriberTrack);
what should I do???
Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using Entity Framework. And you enabled change tracking. In this situation entity object stores the reference to corresponding object context.

So `campaign`, `emailAccount`, or `subscriptions` under suspect (if they are really entities).

And you reference these entities by `campaignSubscriberTrack` which you later try to add to new objectContext, I guess.
Either reference entities with foreign keys, or detach entities prior attaching them to new objectContext.

**More detailed:**

When you query entity from DB there are several ways its state can be affected.

If your entity (POCO I guess)is not a sealed class and contains *virtual* navigation properties and proxy generation is on, Dynamic proxy is generated specially to fixup relationships of the entities.

If scalar properties are virtual as well then in addition to this DynamicProxy helps with change tracking.

Each entity can be either attached to context or detached form it. When you use [AsNoTracking()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev11.query?appId=Dev11IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery%601.AsNoTracking%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version=v4.5%29;k%28DevLang-csharp%29&rd=true) query returns detached entities.
As you can see from the exception the problem is in change tracker.
So you cannot attach entity to a context if it's already attached to another one and change tracking is on.

But if change tracking is off: `AsNoTracking()` or proxies are not generated for POCOs (`context.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false`) you can 'share' entity between contexts.

Please note, that disabling propxies does not mean returning detached entities. They will stay attached, but changes are will be detected only at SaveChanges() when [DetectChanges()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.detectchanges.aspx) is called.

So this exception should tell you that you query entitties with one context whcih is left not disposed  and then you try to attach graph of entities to another context.
And you have to find that place in code where new context is used instead of the old one...or detach loaded entities before attaching them to new contex.

Comment: I did not understand wat that means.. Can u tell me by some example??